# GROUP BY with active record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table (url_analyst) with the following info:

```
id  |  user_id |  url_id |  date          | visits
----------------------------------------------------
1   |  2       |  5      |  2015-10-25    | 15
2   |  2       |  6      |  2015-10-25    | 18
3   |  2       |  5      |  2015-10-25    | 11
4   |  3       |  8      |  2015-10-25    | 22
5   |  3       |  9      |  2015-10-27    | 30
6   |  5       |  15     |  2015-10-25    | 15
```

etc
What I want is a update/insert earning in a new table "earning"
earning calculate 1$/10 visits

```
id  |  user_id |  total_urls |  date          | total_visits | earning
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  2       |  3          |  2015-10-25    | 44           | 4.4$
2   |  3       |  1          |  2015-10-25    | 22           | 2.2$
3   |  3       |  1          |  2015-10-27    | 30           | 3.0$
4   |  5       |  1          |  2015-10-25    | 15           | 1.5$
```

How can I do this with CodeIgniter using the active record query method? Can this be done with COUNT Total URL then GROUP BY user_id AND Date , update earning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    user_id, count(url_id), date, sum(visits) as 
    total_visits, concat(sum(visits)/10,'$') as earning 
FROM
    url_analyst 
GROUP BY
    user_id, date
```

Comment: thank you.. i'm using that for create mysql view table

Answer (score 0):

Considering all `group_by` columns from `url_analyst` table,

```
$this->db->select("SUM(total_url)");//if required select other fields
$this->db->group_by("url_analyst.user_id");
$this->db->group_by("url_analyst.date");
```

If you want `group_by` on any column from `earning`, you can change the table name in `group_by` clause

Comment: thanks for that, when i use coding every time i want update my table, so change that, create via MySQL view table. now finished my work. but i have a problem, now 1$/10 clicks but when i give 2$/10 clicks i can't change on mysql view, so after some days i want to change to coding calculation. that time i can use ur help. thanks again